# Programming PIC16F877a using PICKIT3

Tags: pic, mplab, pickit, pic16f877a

I'm trying to program a pic16f877a using PICKIT3 and MPLAB without success.
I'm powering the pic with the pickit.
I verified the connections almost 20 times, everythings plugged at the right place , every times when I try to burn the pic I get :
**"Too much current has been drawn on VDD. Please disconnect your circuit, check the CLK and DATA lines for shorts and then reconnect."** and **"target device id (0x0) is an invalid device id. please check your connections to the target device"**.
I'm using a RC Oscillator with an arduino since the pic does not have an internal oscillator and I don't have any quartz or battery.
I made a quick schematic using paint to show you my connections using an image that I found on another similar thread([How to connect a dsPic30f2010 to pickit3 icsp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/232243/how-to-connect-a-dspic30f2010-to-pickit3-icsp)).
Thanks !
[image: SCHEMATIC]

Comment: Maybe this?  2.4.4 Debugger Powered
The internal debugger power is limited to 30 mA.

Comment: The PIC16F877A has only two Vdd and two Vss connections. Your diagram is showing three for both. Can you update your schematic with pin numbers?

Comment: Sorry, did not see it, it's done.

Comment: What is powering the Arduino?

Comment: An ac/dc adaptator

Comment: I ran into that problem because I had selected a debug header in the project properties (in other words I had erroneously told the development software that I had a debugger adapter board connected). So the software wasn't accessing the PIC correctly because I had no debug adapter board installed.

Comment: Your schematics show a shot in Vdd and Vss near the C3 decoupling capacitor (100 nF). i also doubt the presence of a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Power the PIC from the same power supply as the Arduino. Remove the Vdd connection to the PIC from the PICKIT3. It may also help to add a 10k resistor from PGM on the PIC to ground. Make sure you have your PICKIT3 set to the correct processor.

You should then be able to program the PIC.